# Does every fermion loop have two contributions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, fermions

Suppose I have a Feynman Diagram with a closed fermion loop. This introduces a negative sign, and a trace over the product of the propagators.

> Is the same Feynman diagram, but with the arrows in the loop going in the opposite direction, a distinct diagram? In other words, are there really two diagrams, which we can take into account by introducing a factor of 2?

If the answer to the above is “yes,” then does this also apply to ghost diagrams?

Comment: Well, Dirac fermion lines, ghost lines & complex scalar lines are oriented.

Comment: It's the other way around. A loop diagram with Majorana fermions has no arrows on the fermion lines and gets a symmetry factor of $1/2$

Answer (score 1):

I have been wondering a similar thing about symmetry factors for fermion loops. Based on [this solution](https://zzxianyu.files.wordpress.com/2017/01/peskin_problems.pdf) for the beta function of the Gross-Neveu model (problem 12.2), for diagrams where the two fermion propagators are oriented in the same direction you get a factor of 2 since you can exchange the two propagators and get an identical diagram. If the arrows are oppositely oriented, you don't get a symmetry factor since you can't exchange them while preserving the diagram. So for example, diagram (b) below gets an overall $1/2$ while the others don't. This is consistent with the rules in for example equation 30 in [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.314.735&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

I explained in more detail how to deduce the symmetry factors [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/750001/fermi-statistics-in-the-feynman-rules-for-the-gross-neveu-model/750493#750493).

[image: Diagrams from the Gross-Neveu model]